# php mysql conditional query AND OR

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a code like this and variables which are selected by user in check-able form

```
SELECT
FROM
WHERE

 product = 'Super Model'
 AND Model = 'Model1'
 OR Model = 'Model2'
 OR Model = 'Model3'
 OR Model = 'Model4'

GROUP BY
```

And check list look like:

Choose Models:

- Model1
- Model2
- Model3
- Model4

I want to make this query dynamic. I would make a switch case statement for this.

```
switch ($model) {

    case "Model1":
        $models = " AND Model = 'Model1' ";
    break;

    case "Model2":
        $models = " OR Model = 'Model2' ";
    break;

    case "Model3":
        $models = " OR Model = 'Model3' ";
    break;

    case "Model4":
        $models = " OR Model = 'Model4' ";
    break;
}
```

But there are problems:
1. It works only for one variable
2. If a user will choose i.e. model2 and model3 string will begin with OR statement, which is not logical as it suppose to start with AND.

I tried with something like this:

```
$models = " AND '.$model[0].' OR '.$model[1].' OR '.$model[2].'  OR '.$model[3].'  OR '.$model[4].' ";
```

then I put $models in WHERE statement but it doesn't work. And I have noticed problems:
1. If user will select only 2 models, probably statement will look like: " AND Model2 OR Model3 OR OR OR "
2. It is not dynamic, I would like to have something like: "for every item in the array do sth".

So maybe foreach? But how to deal with this AND at the beginning and OR between other models?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you get the values in an array, use the `IN` statement in your query;. It would be something like `AND Model in ('model1', 'model2', 'model3')` and so on.

Comment: You just need to concatenate the values with the quotes

Comment: is `$model` an array ?

Comment: yes, $model is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to be careful with your logical operator combination (See this page about mysql operator precedence) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html ), lets look at some examples:

```
mysql> select TRUE AND TRUE OR FALSE;
+------------------------+
| TRUE AND TRUE OR FALSE |
+------------------------+
|                      1 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here we see an AND followed by an or that gives the expect result (product matches and the first model matches)

```
mysql> select FALSE AND FALSE OR TRUE;
+-------------------------+
| FALSE AND FALSE OR TRUE |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But in this example the product doesn't match but if the model matches you will still get results. From your question this looks like this is not something you want.

```
mysql> select FALSE AND (FALSE OR TRUE);
+---------------------------+
| FALSE AND (FALSE OR TRUE) |
+---------------------------+
|                         0 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Adding ( ) around your OR section will result in the product having to match as well as one of the selected models.

With that said a simple solution would be to use and IN clause (as this has simialr behaviour to an (...OR...OR...OR...) etc

```
WHERE  product = 'Super Model' AND Model IN ('Model1','Model2','Model3','Model4')
```

The in clause can be gained from PHP with:

```
$models_string = "AND model IN ('".implode("','",$model)."')";
```

But you would need to check that the $model array had elements.

If you wanted to use OR statements you could do something like the following:

```
$models = '';
if(count($model) > 0 ){
   $models .= ' AND ( FALSE';
   foreach($model => $m){
      $models .= " OR model = '$m'";
   }
   $models .= ')';
}
```

(I have not tested that code so there might be a typo but I think the logic is sound).

Comment: works like a charm :) $models_string saves a lot of my time! thnks

Answer (score 0):

```
$models = array($model1, $model2, $model3, $model4, $model5);
$models = implode(',', $models);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE product = 'Super Model' AND FIND_IN_SET(Model, $models);
```